# Want to use volumes in my running Docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a docker container that is currently running on my ubuntu server.

The container is basically running nginx and mysql on it, but currently it isn't using volumes so if I destroy the container my data is gone.

The DockerFile was updated with the following:

```
VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql", "/opt/nginx/www"]
```

I want to create the following folders on my host machine like:

```
/home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/mysql
/home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/www
```

How can I start a container and use the 2 folders I created above for mysql and my nginx/www files.

**I'm confused what the VOLUME command does inside of a DockerFile, and what the -v command does when starting a container.  How are they related?  Really hoping someone can explain this for me.**

Also, is it possible for me to do this with an already running container or will I have to stop and destroy my current container b/c it was setup with volumes?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I start a container and use the 2 folders I created above for mysql and my nginx/www files.

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -v /home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/www:/opt/nginx/www image_name
```

The above command will mount your host directories as data volumes in the container when it runs. The pattern for the `-v` flag is:

```
-v /path/on/host:/path/in/container
```

> I'm confused what the VOLUME command does inside of a DockerFile, and what the -v command does when starting a container. How are they related? Really hoping someone can explain this for me.

I believe declaring a volume in the Dockerfile is functionally equivalent to using the `-v` CLI flag like this: (corrections welcome)

```
docker run -v /data image_name

VOLUME /data
```

Mount-points for the volumes are created when the container is created. [More info from Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

You can retrieve files from the existing container before you destroy it using the [export command](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#export).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused what the VOLUME command does inside of a DockerFile, and
>   what the -v command does when starting a container. How are they
>   related? Really hoping someone can explain this for me.

The `VOLUME` command inside a Dockerfile simply marks a directory as "not part of the container filesystem", such that it's contents will not be included in a generated image nor will they be committed when you run `docker commit`.  It also makes the directory available to other containers that are started with the `--volumes-from` argument.

The `-v` command line option, when given a simple pathname, performs the same as the `VOLUME` command.  When given a `hostpath:containerpath` argument, mounts the specified `hostpath` inside the container at `containerpath.`  In either case, the volume is available via `--volumes-from` to other containers.

It is not necessary to have a `VOLUME` directive in your `Dockerfile` in order to use the `-v` command line option, but you often will in any case to clearly identify the data directories.

For your two directories:

```
/home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/mysql
/home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/www
```

You would:

```
docker run \
  -v /home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
  -v /home/ubuntu/container_data/container1/www:/opt/nginx/www \
  ...
```